# What does **They're rare, them** mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> "Well, I've bin doin' some readin'," said Hagrid, pulling a large book from under his pillow. "Got this outta the library -- *Dragon Breeding for Pleasure and Profit* -- It's a bit outta date, o' course, but it's all in here. Keep the egg in the fire, 'cause their mothers breathe on 'em, see, an' when it hatches, feed it on a bucket o' brandy mixed with chicken blood every half hour. An' see here -- how ter recognize diff'rent eggs -- what I got there's a Norwegian Ridgeback. **They're rare, them**."

What's the sentence "**They're rare, them**" conveying?  I can figure out '**they**' refers to "*Norwegian Ridgeback eggs*", but I don't understand what '**them**' is doing there? I feel the structure of the sentence is unusual, so I'm not sure if this kind of sentence construction has some special effect. Is it a part of standard English structures, which I'm not yet familiar with?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: *Norwegian Ridgeback eggs are rare.*

Comment: @JasonBassford, what is 'them' doing there? That's my main confusion. I can figure out 'they' refers to "Norwegian Ridgeback eggs".

Comment: @dan I think the 'them' also refers to Norwegian Ridgeback. It's like a reaffirmation.

Comment: @Albert, I just feel the structure is odd, maybe it's not odd but I'm just not familiar with it.

Comment: @dan yeah, it also sounds weird to me. Maybe because it's British?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a pronoun in that way, I'm tired, me, you're crazy, you, they're rare, them, is used in some English regional dialects.

Comment: Any effect for it to be used that way?

Comment: Mild emphasis or affirmation, I suppose.